# powerpivot inner join

Tags: sql, excel, powerpivot

I have one table:

```
Person Name Country code
Andrew      1
Philip      2
John        1
Daniel      2
```

and a lookup table:

```
Country code    Country name
1               USA
2               UK
```

I added them to powerpivot, created a relationship between the country code fields, then I created a pivot table.  I expect to get the following:

```
Person Name Country code
Andrew      USA
Philip      UK
John        USA
Daniel      UK
```

But what I actually get is:

```
Person Name Country code
Andrew      USA
Andrew      UK
Philip      USA
Philip      UK
John        USA
John        UK
Daniel      USA
Daniel      UK
```

Comment: What do you expect PowerPivot to add to the picture? You could get the wanted like `SELECT PT.personName, LT.countryName FROM PersonTable PT JOIN LookupTable LT ON PT.countryCode = LT.countryCode`.

Comment: These two tables are from different sources.  I need to do the join in PowerPivot.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options:

1. Add a column to your main table that uses a formula to pull in the Country Name from your LookUp Table e.g.
   `=RELATED(LookUpTable[Country Name])`
2. If you drag in any measure that references the main table you will get your desired result e.g. `=COUNTROWS('MainTable')` You then hide the results column if you had to.